# Mac Pro, OSX 10.9.5, Mirror Display to Raritan Cat 5 Reach KVM

Tags: multiple-monitors, osx-mavericks, kvm-switch

I can get my MacBook Pro, OSX 10.9.5 to work fine, using the Raritan KVM. As well as a Mac Mini, with the same OS. When I try to use the MacPro, the computer the KVM is intended for, It doesn't even see it.

I've tried different adapters, different cables, both thunderbolt and HDMI outputs of the MacPro.

I tried different Thunderbolt busses (the Mac Pro has 3 busses and 6 ports).

I tried that hold option key and detect display, thing.

When I go to "about this mac" and get a system report, it doesn't see that anything is even plugged in, when I'm using the thunderbolt to DVI.

I thought maybe because the MacBook has a built in display, that If I have a display hooked up to the macpro, while also having the KVM connected...no dice.

The graphics card for the macbook pro is intel, and the macpro is amd. Is this the reason?

[KVM URL](https://www.raritan.com/products/kvm-serial/accessories/cat5-dvi-and-vga-extender)

Anyone have any terminal scripts, to force video output?

Any Ideas?

---

I just put my MBP in target disk mode, and booted it from the MP, to rule out a hardware issue. The MP worked, booting from the MBP disk, so it is a software issue.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried putting the mac to sleep and then waiting a few seconds then waking it up and see if it connects to the display?

Comment: I guess not. I'll try right now.

Comment: This didn't fix it, btw. I'm still having to use my MBP as a go between. :(